# Call one function from another python

Tags: python

I am new python programmer and trying to write Python class with 2 functions and calling one from another.

below is my code, can someone please help me in fixing the code.

```py
class Solution:
    def repeat_check(string):
        for i in range(1, len(string)//2+1):
            if not len(string)%len(string[0:i]) and string[0:i]*(len(string)//len(string[0:i])) == string:
                return string[0:i]
            
    def fractionToDecimal(self, numerator: int, denominator: int) -> str:
        fraction = str(numerator/denominator)
        decimal_pos = fraction.index('.')
        repeat_string = str(fraction[decimal_pos+1:])
        if numerator%denominator==0:
             return fraction
            
        elif numerator%denominator!=0 and repeat_check(repeat_string) is None:
             return repeat_string
            
        elif numerator%denominator!=0 and repeat_check(repeat_string).isdigit():
              return fraction+'.('+repeat_string+')'
```

I got error message name "repeat_check is not defined"

```
    input 
    numerator = 2 denominator = 3
    output
     0.(6)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing "self" in the repeat_check method:

```python
class Solution:
    def repeat_check(self, string):
        for i in range(1, len(string) // 2 + 1):
            if not len(string) % len(string[0:i]) and string[0:i] * (len(string) // len(string[0:i])) == string:
                return string[0:i]


    def fractionToDecimal(self, numerator: int, denominator: int) -> str:
        fraction = str(numerator / denominator)
        decimal_pos = fraction.index('.')
        repeat_string = str(fraction[decimal_pos + 1:])
        if numerator % denominator == 0:
            return fraction

        elif numerator % denominator != 0 and self.repeat_check(repeat_string) is None:
            return repeat_string

        elif numerator % denominator != 0 and self.repeat_check(repeat_string).isdigit():
            return fraction + '.(' + repeat_string + ')'
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I reccomend you to make indents. Therefore the Function will be a field of the class.

Scond: Every Function of the class gets the "self" argument. and then you can refer it with self.repeat_check().

Best regards